# How to solve file not found error with file present?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, jupyter-notebook, xlsx

I have a xlsx file to be used in a jupyter notebook with the following code

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 

file_name = "D:/Revenue Forecasting/my_sheet.xlsx"

sheet = "sheet2"

historical_input_data_df = pd.read_excel(io=file_name, sheet_name=sheet)
```

The file is the same location , but it keep saying no such file or directory. can anyone help me with this ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if sheet name you have given is same , as by default it should start with capital S.
2. Try removing blank space in folder name , it works with space but not sure why its not working in yours.
3. If error still persist , try to paste the exact error code in comment for a better look.

Comment: It was a blank space error. Thanks .

Comment: @VigneshwaranRajasekaran ...Happy to help :)